# Returning value of an item price in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying add easy updating prices into a google sheet.
I need the market price from

`//*[@id="app"]/div/section[2]/section/div[1]/section[3]/div/section[1]/ul/li[1]/span[2]`

https://www.tcgplayer.com/product/242811/pokemon-celebrations-celebrations-elite-trainer-box?Language=English

I need it to display just the one number from the XPath to a cell, and I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong. I've been using the IMPORTXML function and it won't return a value.

`=IMPORTXML(A2,"//*[@id='app']/div/section[2]/section/div[1]/section[3]/div/section[1]/ul/li[1]/span[2]")`

where A2 is the URL.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, it seems that the value of `the market price` cannot be directly retrieved from the URL of `https://www.tcgplayer.com/product/242811/pokemon-celebrations-celebrations-elite-trainer-box?Language=English`. But, fortunately, it seems that that value can be directly retrieved from the endpoint of API. So, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN(",",IMPORTDATA(A1)),"marketPrice:(.+?),")*1
```

or

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA(A1)),"WHERE Col1 matches 'marketPrice.+'"),"marketPrice:(.+)")*1
```

- The cell "A1" has the URL of `https://mpapi.tcgplayer.com/v2/product/242811/details`.
- In the case of `https://www.tcgplayer.com/product/242811/pokemon-celebrations-celebrations-elite-trainer-box?Language=English`, please use `242811` from the URL to the endpoint of API like `https://mpapi.tcgplayer.com/v2/product/242811/details`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- The value from the URL is JSON data. In this case, the following custom function can be also used. In this case, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. And please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE("url")` to a cell.

  ```
    const SAMPLE = url => JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()).marketPrice;
  ```

#### References:

- [IMPORTDATA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335)
- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to scrape JS content into google sheets:

[image]